How to use "film club"
I want to ask two question about "film club".

I think "film club" is the only category that needs the definite article. Is it good to use the definite article with only 'film club' and not the other categories?

The chart description says those categories are activities but is it correct to call the film club an activity?



The film club was the most popular activity in 2000 and the
martial arts the second most popular. (I wrote this sentence.)



How many film clubs are there? Is it a particular film club? And  are the other figures for a martial arts club, an amateur dramatics society, etc? I don't think it necessarily matters much whether you use "the" or not, but you should try and be consistent (although it's difficult if you're presented with data that's inconsistent - are other activities organised in clubs/societies?)

Some of the rules that govern speech are suspended when referring to texts of various kinds (literary, legal, charts, etc).  You can use the labels on the chart to refer to its data categories. You're not referring to the film club per se but to a datum.


Yes, it's appropriate  to use the definite article because the film club based at this particular centre is an organisation; the others are types of activity.

Being a member of this club presumably entails going to meetings and watching films, so it's an activity by implication. It would be pedantic to put something like 'attending film club meetings' on the graph just so that all the labels have the same grammatical function.



I agree that the other activities should not have the definite article. But I think it's no more than optional for Film club. Compare this: The first rule of Fight Club is: Don't talk about Fight Club.

@PeterKirkpatrick, if I don’t use ‘the,’ I need to capitalize ‘Film Club,’ but the other activities remain in lowercase. Is this good?

That sounds right to me. Capitals would not be because "the" is missing; they would be because you are interpreting Film Club as the name of the group activity.
